# Can deplete be used in relation to time?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

The title is self explanatory.

Could something like the following be said:

"Our time is depleting..."?

Comment: No, the typical construction is "*Our time is running out*".

Comment: @DanBron Thanks, would it however be absolutely unreasonable even in a poetic form?

Comment: Well, so far as I can from [Google nGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=time+is+depleting&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=) and the [COCA Corpus](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/?c=coca&q=41500695), literally no one has phrased it that way before, if that tells you anything. Note one reason for this is that there is no intransitive sense for *depleting*; it's always the subject depleting the object. In other words, you can say "*X is depleting Y*", but you don't typically saying "*Y are depleting*": you say "*Y stocks are being depleted*".

Comment: I tend to agree with Dan Bron. However I'm not sure that, 'Our time is being depleted" is any better. I think of supplies, stocks or stores *of* a commodity as being capable of being depleted rather than the commodity itself.

Comment: I don't think the progressive intransitive is a good choice. A passive causative is better if you wanna use the progressive: _Our time is being depleted._ Depletion is frequently mentioned in terms of a rate, but the rate of depletion of time is one second per second, which is not helpful, or even sensible. So I think _deplete_ would not be a good choice with time. You can [waste time or spend time or need time](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/TIM.pdf), but depletion is something else.

Comment: *Deplete* is not a common choice with time. But it is possible to use it in connection with time, or any other resource or quantity that is limited. **Being limited is the key.** A given period of available time can be depleted. Time itself cannot be depleted, unless there is an end to time.

Comment: Certainly one can, eg, deplete the "buffer" time built into something like a construction schedule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can absolutely use "deplete" with time. We have (generally) a measured supply of time as humans. i.e. life expectancies. Time is also a supply and a resource, in that we can choose to either use it wisely or waste it. When you say that time is depleting it can either mean that time is being used up or diminishing in how much remains. Especially for poetic use it is perfectly usable.

Although time unto itself, in a philosophy sense, cannot be depleted, time, in a horology sense, can be, since we all measure, watch, use and navigate time like any other resource.

I followed all the rules, said no great poet ever.

Answer (score 0):

It is semantically wrong to use depleting for time. You cannot deplete time because time itself is an infinite quantity. However, if you use it in conjunction with a noun of sorts, it may make more sense since the supply of time for that person / object is being depleted, rather than time itself, that is:

> The dog's time was depleting

The above statement is *rightfully* not sympathetic to the idea that time, an infinite quantity, is being depleted. This to me is clear and to a degree, I can, by the principle of charity, work out what you mean.